# How can I safely use an un-initialized array in a UITableView and show an empty table

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

How to prevent crashes when an array is empty and you make a request from a UITableView or UIPickerView?

My current method is to always initialize my arrays before using them with dummy data but I'm not really happy with this method since sometimes the dummy data is not needed and even-worse, sometimes it doesn't even make sense to show the data, in fact most of the time what I want is to show an empty table if there is no data.

For instance if I will be retrieving an array from `NSUserDefaults` to be used in a `UITableView` I usually initialize it in the `AppDelegate` as follow...

AppDelegate.swift:

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults([
        keyMyAarray:["Dummy Data"]// initializing array
     ])
```

SomeViewController:

```
var myArray = read content from NSUserDefaults...

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

fun tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Again, how can I safely use an un-initialized array in a `UITableView` and show an empty table?

Comment: if your `myArray`  not have any element then it will definitely show the empty table!

Comment: `return myArray.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` ensures that.

Comment: And this will not crash the app at some point? I have seen errors/crashes caused by the used of an uninitialized arrays.

Comment: @ NSNoob, I see, thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre I though you wanted to keep the empty rows in the view... :)

Comment: No, I just want an empty table if the array is empty, but thank you, it's good to know that it is possible to add empty rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to put "dummy data" in your array. You can just initilize an empty array. like below

```
    var myArray = [String]()
```

And in `numberOfRowsInSection` return myArray.count. If count is zero, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not be called and you are safe to go.

Answer (score 1):

3 empty rows by default.

```
var myArray:Array<String>? = ...

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

fun tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray?.count ?? 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if let arrayStrings = myArray, arrayStrings.count > indexPath.row {
       cell.textLabel.text = arrayStrings[indexPath.row]
    } 
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Good to know you can add empty rows. Thanks